# What is the noun for either a file or folder?

Tags: file, directory

We have files and directories; what is the noun that we could use to generically describe both of these? 
For example, an apple or a orange can generically be described as fruit. Is there such a word?

"file system object" looks lengthy, have any short term?

Comment: Hi, The term could be filesystem object

Comment: "file system object" looks lengthy, have any short term ?

Comment: However, your question belongs on english.stackexchange.com